# Hibernate ClobJdbcType bindings: what are the diferences?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jdbc, clob

Hibernate `ClobJdbcType` provides several binder types, but it's not documented and not so obvious for all developers.
What  are the "benefits" of:

- *Stream* vs simple *String* binder? (guess streams could have better performance on LOB types? )
- *Extracting* (`STREAM_BINDING_EXTRACTING` vs `STREAM_BINDING`)?

Bonus question: `ClobJdbcType#STREAM_BINDING_EXTRACTING` uses `CallableStatement#setCharacterStream(String, Reader, long)`, but `PgPreparedStatement#setCharacterStream(String, Reader, long)` has been never implemented for **`long`** stream length. Why?